# SQL update based on user input with IN list and/or loop

Tags: sql, sql-update

I need to write an update that takes a users input text (below) and and runs the updates that have working (needs to do this).  I think that I need to use some type of loop or cursor.  It is possible that the *reference* column has other text not just 'FUEL=?'.  The users know that the format must be 'FUEL=?' for this update to work.  I am unable to add addition columns to the table at this time.  I am new at this.. thanks for all your help!!

#### Users Input will be the following:

Fuel Group = A, C

New Surcharge = 2

#### Need to do this

```
update tblroutes
set DriverSurcharge = 2
where Reference like '%FUEL=A%' or  Reference like '%FUEL=C%'
```

#### Table to start

RouteID | Reference | Surcharge

F01 | Windows FUEL=A | 0

F02 | FUEL=A | 0

F03 | FUEL=B | 0

F04 | Win 8 FUEL=B | 0

F05 | FUEL=C | 0

F06 | FUEL=C MAC | 0

F07 | FUEL=D | 0

#### End result wanted

RouteID | Reference | Surcharge

F01 | Windows FUEL=A | 2

F02 | FUEL=A | 2

F03 | FUEL=B | 0

F04 | Win 8 FUEL=B | 0

F05 | FUEL=C | 2

F06 | FUEL=C MAC | 2

F07 | FUEL=D | 0

I can get 1 'Fuel Group' to update at a time but want to give the user the ability to run the update to as many groups as they want at one time.

```
DECLARE @Surcharge INT
DECLARE @Group Varchar

--This will give the user a input box for surcharge amount
--SET @Surcharge= '<< Please enter surcharge amount. >>'
----This will give the user a input box for fuel group(s)
--SET @Group= '<< Please enter fuel group(s). >>'

--If the user entered 4 & A
SET @Surcharge= '4'
SET @Group= 'A'

update tblroutes
set DriverSurcharge = @Surcharge
where Reference like '%FUEL='+@Group+'%'
```

Now how do i handle if the user enters Fuel Group = A, C

Comment: what exactly is your question ? the SQL update statement you posted will do what you want without using any loops. Are you asking how to do it in a programming language? and if so, which one?

Comment: Need to be done in T-SQL. I need the update to happen dynamically based on user input.

Comment: where exactly is this user going to enter this data ? in a desktop application? on a website ? a little more context would be great

Comment: a desktop app.  The answer is reserved as a single string for each question asked. So based on my example above Fuel Group = A, C, would be sent to sql as 'A,C'

Comment: i think you need to ask a question about how to do CRUD operations in C# or java or something, you seem to have the SQL part down.

Comment: no access to other programs. has to be done in SQL

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your main problem is parsing the user input in SQL.
And the parsing actually means splitting a string. As soon as you have the separate values in a temporary table or table variable, you can run your (already created) query in a loop.

Have a look at this question and answer: [How do I split a string so I can access item x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/split-string-in-sql)